# Plotly: Change space between legend entries?

Tags: python, plotly

How can I reduce the separation/spacing between legend entries in Plotly? Making the legend font smaller only has so much impact. I want to do this because my real case has *a lot* of entries and I need to compact them.

Here is a Python Plotly Express example, but doubt the frontend language matters. Note the huge amount of space between "Female, No", "Female, Yes", etc. in the legend:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="sex", symbol="smoker", facet_col="time",
          labels={"sex": "Gender", "smoker": "Smokes"})

fig.update_layout(
    legend=dict(
        font=dict(
            size=6,
        ),
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can *change* the space between legend entries using, for example:

```
fig.layout.legend.tracegroupgap = 10
```

But the default value is `0` so you can't *decrease* it any furher like you're trying to do here. The only accepted interval is `[0, inf]`. If you should try a negative number you'd get:

> ValueError:
> Invalid value of type 'builtins.int' received for the 'tracegroupgap' property of layout.legend
> Received value: -1

So unfortunately there does not seem to be a direct way to do what you're aiming for at the time being.